# Tomcat DB Connection Pooling with Struts2

Tags: tomcat, struts2

Working on an app using Struts2, Tomcat 7 and an oracle database. Right now I have it working with simple JDBC connection set up for each action but I would like to use connection pooling. I tried to follow the following tutorial since I could not find one specifically for Struts 2:
 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/database-connection-pooling-tomcat-eclipse-db/

What additions/changes would be required to use this with Struts2? Can I just call doGet() and have it return a String to display corresponding webpage (like a typical execute method would)?

Or is there an alternative for managing db connections in a Struts2 app? (without using another framework such as Spring or Hibernate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you *could* manage (with a big effort) your self-made connection pool directly,

usually `Connection Pooling` is performed by the Application Server in a transparent way.

You can configure your DataSource on your Tomcat or directly from your application, [like described in this article](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/servlet/servlet-jndi-datasource-in-tomcat/).

Answer (score 3):

The database connectivity has nothing to do with Struts.  The right way to do it is spelled out in the [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).